# How to set a global Base URL for every test case of one test suite in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium

How to set a global Base URL for every test case of one test suite in Selenium IDE so that I can switch to different environment easily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just created a separate test and put it at the top of all tests. Store the base url to an variable and now I am able to access it in other test cases by ${variable_name}.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I tried putting ${variable_name} in the base url and in the open command and in both cases it's not being replaced by the value I previously set it to. Can you give a little more detail on how you did this? Thanks!

Comment: Feh. I had the arguments to "store" backwards.

Comment: Can someone provide some more detail on this strategy?  I can't get it to work.  Selenium doesn't seem to evaluate `${variables}` in the link element, and trying to `store` a value back into `selenium.base` in later tests doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can't use `${variable}` in the URL. Instead, just don't put the `base_url` into the Selenium script. Either set it manually before running the test case or suite. Personally, I wrote a test scaffold script that constructed suites from a set of test cases, with the purpose of mapping the `base_url` in the first test case in the suite.

Answer (score 33):

If you have a lot of test cases in a single suite, it's a pain to change the Base URL for each. Instead, create a separate case for each Base URL you need to switch between. For example, I have `store https://testing.site.com/` as `myEnvironment` saved as test case SetEnvTesting. I create another case for my production site, SetEnvProduction.

Then, insert the `${myEnvironment}` at the beginning of each relative URL in your test cases. For example, `open ${myEnvironment}/login.aspx`. (This might be a pain if you've got a lot of tests already. I suggest just adding it from now on.) Then, simply put the set-environment test case at the beginning of your test suite. To switch your entire suite to another Base URL, simply put a different set-environment case at the start. Another nice thing is that you can switch environments in the middle of the suite by putting a different set-environment case in the middle.

**Edit: Example of using a SetEnvironment test case.**

The SetEnvironment case:
[image]

An example of a following test case.
[image]

Notice

1. how the CurrentEnvironment variable is used. You can do this for every case in the suite. Additionally, you can make every separate test suite use this same SetEnvironment case, so they all switch together.
2. that the Base Url becomes irrelevant. You're overriding it, essentially.

I hope that's helpful!

Comment: Can you post the myEnvironment script?

Comment: @arwenvh re: "it's a pain to change the Base URL for each"
I used this linux/bash command to replace all the offending lines in my test cases (all with .tc extension) `find /path/to/your/testcases -type f -name "*.tc" -exec sed -i "s/.*selenium.base.*/<!-- selenium.base removed by cleaner script -->/" '{}' \;`

Answer (score 12):

The test case HTML file is responsible for setting the base URL. From the Selenium IDE, you can override the base URL for a test case. A test suite, on the other hand, is only a bag for your test cases.

Remove the base URL setting from each of the test case files referenced from your test suite. Then set the base URL by hand for the test suite and run the suite.

The line in question is in the head of each test case file:

```
<link href="http://server-name/" rel="selenium.base"/>
```

If it is missing, then the base URL overrides it automatically.

Answer (score 9):

I found it *exceedingly frustrating* that I couldn't just have a blank Base URL and have it use whatever page I already had open as the start of the test. What is the point of being able to record **relative** URLs when it forces you to **hardcode a base url** that is prefixed to every relative url (thus turning them into absoulte urls)??

Extending on the other answers and from this question: [In Selenium IDE, how to get the value of the base url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203620/in-selenium-ide-how-to-get-the-value-of-the-base-url)

You can store the current domain in a variable and then use that instead of a hard coded one. This lets you login to the server you want to run the tests on, hit play and it will run the tests without all this baseURL nonsense redirecting you to the wrong server.

Just use these commands at the start of the first script in your suite:
[image: store current server]

And keep using the `http://${host}/` syntax for every **truly relative** URL you need in your script.

Comment: I prefer to use **window.location.origin**, as it will include the protocol and optional port, so I do not need to make assumptions about them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the accepted answer, it does work for selenium IDE, but it does not work when running [stand-alone server](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list).

finally, I put the value inside the [user-extensions.js](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.jsp) , and use storeEval to get the value back. Then the same value could be retrieved inside different cases.

EDIT:

In the user-extensions.js, add the following

```js
var selenium_base_url = "http://example.com"
```

In the HTLM suite, add the following

```html
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>selenium_base_url</td>
    <td>case_base_url</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>${case_base_url}/case_path?a=1&b=2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This may look odd at the first sight, but actually `user-extension.js` could be modified on the fly right before the `stand-alone server` execution, so you may put a different base url using a script in the real QA scenario.

Comment: Hello @Walty Yeung, do you have any example about your .js extension ? Tks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think there is a simpler solution:

- In the first test (of the test suite) adjust
  `<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://google.com" />` as needed
- In the following tests remove (using text editor or similar):
  `<link rel="selenium.base" ... />`

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine double clicking multiple times,

1. Double click the top one, set it to the URL you want.
2. Now double click the top, middle, bottom.
3. Now double click the bottom, middle, top.

Answer (score 0):

I created a user-extension command 'doBaseURL' that manipulates the Selenium IDE field 'Base URL'.
In every test case of a test suite I added this command `| baseURL | | |`. Below the surface it sets a stored variable named baseURL.
It is possible to give the stored variable 'baseURL' a value from a test case command prior to the first 'baseURL' command.
This method overwrites the `<link href="http://server-name/" rel="selenium.base"/>` setting of each test case file.
For me this works fine as now the Selenium IDE reflects the Base URL that the test case(s) will use (or was using when an error occured).

The java script is:

```
Selenium.prototype.doBaseURL = function(strTarget, strValue) {
/**
  * Enables a more predictive Base URL when running a test suite with multiple test cases. 
  * On first usage it wil fill a stored variable 'baseURL' either with the given strTarget,
  * or when not given with the Base URL as shown on the Selenium IDE UI. The Selenium IDE UI field
  * Base URL is updated to reflect the (new) base URL. 
  * In each subsequent test case with a baseURL command the stored variable 'baseURL' will determine
  * the base.
  *
  * <p> Best to use as first command in each test case and only in the first test case a strTarget
  * argument, in that way the test cases of a test suite will no longer depend on their 'hidden'
  * '<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://www.something.com/" />
  * construction, that makes test cases effectively having an absolute base URL.
  * </p>
  *
  * @param strTarget a Base URL value to be used in the test case (e.g. https://www.google.com/)
  */

// pushes the given strTarget into the selenium.browserbot.baseUrl
// and makes the new Base URL value visible on the Selenium IDE UI.
// A subsequent open command will use this new Base URL value

LOG.debug("begin: doBaseURL | " + strTarget + " | " + strValue + " |");

// note:    window.location.href = strTarget;      causes the browser to replace Selenium-IDE UI with the given url
// used that knowledge to manipulate the Selenium IDE UI as if a manual Base URL change was done.
LOG.debug("window.location.href= [" + window.location.href + "]");
LOG.debug("window.editor.app.getBaseURL() gives [" + window.editor.app.getBaseURL() + "]");

if (strTarget && (strTarget.substring(0,1)!="$")) { // only when strTaget has a value

strValue = "Base URL changed from [" + selenium.browserbot.baseUrl.toString() + "] into [" + strTarget + "]"; 
selenium.browserbot.baseUrl = strTarget.toString();

// set the visible Base URL value on the Selenium IDE UI to the new value
window.editor.app.setBaseURL(strTarget);
LOG.debug("updated into: " + window.editor.app.getBaseURL());

// remember this value for future calls
storedVars["baseURL"] = window.editor.app.getBaseURL();
LOG.debug("storedVars[\"baseURL\"] set to [" + window.editor.app.getBaseURL() + "]");

} else {
// no value =>  take storeVars["baseURL"] when set;
//      otherwise take Selenium IDE Base URL field.
if ((storedVars["baseURL"] != undefined) && (storedVars["baseURL"] != "")) {
    strValue = "Base URL changed from [" + selenium.browserbot.baseUrl.toString() + "] into [" + storedVars["baseURL"] + "]"; 
    selenium.browserbot.baseUrl = storedVars["baseURL"];

    // set the visible Base URL value on the Selenium IDE UI to the new value
    window.editor.app.setBaseURL(storedVars["baseURL"]);
    LOG.debug("updated from storedVars[\"baseURL\"]");
} else {
    strValue = "Base URL changed from [" + selenium.browserbot.baseUrl.toString() + "] into [" + window.editor.app.getBaseURL() + "]"; 
        selenium.browserbot.baseUrl = window.editor.app.getBaseURL();

    // remember this value for future calls
    storedVars["baseURL"] = window.editor.app.getBaseURL();
    LOG.debug("storedVars[\"baseURL\"] set to [" + window.editor.app.getBaseURL() + "]");
}
}
LOG.info(strValue);
LOG.debug("end: doBaseURL | " + strTarget + " | " + strValue + " |");
}
```

Installing a user-extension script is explained in the "Using User-Extensions With Selenium-IDE" section SeleniumHQ documentation: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.jsp