# how do I get URL with selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have look over the internet and didn't find an answer
I am trying to store the URL in a variable.
Found couple of answer that didn't work

1. [${!url}](https://ui.vision/docs#internalvar) should bring read-only URL of the site
2. ["StoreLocation"](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2012/11/storelocation-and-storetitle-commands.html) should store the URL and that doesn't exist in the IDE
3. [storeEval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203620/in-selenium-ide-how-to-get-the-value-of-the-base-url/33657544) should store the URL and that doesn't exist in the IDE

Answer (score 8):

For reference, this is what this looks like in the Selenium IDE

[image]
[image]

You can then assert that the result is a given value like so:

[image]

There's some more useful info here too - https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/

Comment: If the page redirected to a PDF file, it will not let you execute scripts. Which makes sense, but leaves no options for asserting URL's in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [execute-script](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#execute-script) command like this:

```
execute script | return window.location.href; | url
```

So after execution of this command `url` variable will store url of page.

Comment: This just returns the browser extension url. You have to use "open" first (without any arguments it looks like it opens the website url).